# How can I iterate through a list with multiple objects from class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am coding an application for my study, but i'm stuck at this point. I made a class called 'Neighborhood'. This class has a string and an int. In my main code I give the class a value and put it in a list. I now want to loop through my list and get the int out of it (put it in a listbox, or do a calculation). How do I get the int out of the list?

```
class Wijk
    {
        private string wijken;
        private int tijd;


        public string Wijken
        {
            get { return wijken; }
            set { wijken = value; }
        }

        public int Tijd
        {
            get { return tijd; }
            set { tijd = value; }
        }
    }
```

Created the list and the instance of the class.

```
    List<object> Uden = new List<object>();
    Wijk Wijkeninput = new Wijk();
```

Now I value the string and int with a combobox and textbox.

```
private void wijkAanmaken()
        {
            Wijkeninput.Wijken = Convert.ToString(cbWijken);
            Wijkeninput.Tijd = Convert.ToInt16(tbSnelheid.Text);
            Uden.Add(Wijkeninput);
        }
```

Comment: Hey I answered your question first.  If my answer works or you. Please mark as answered. Or mark the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

For this, instead of having an object list, you can have list containing class objects like

```
List<Wjik> Uden = new List<Wjik>();
```

then you can access int as follows:

```
foreach (Wjik obj in listProgram)
{
    int tij = Convert.ToInt32(obj.tijd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the List can be declared like this:

```
List<Wijk> Uden = new List<Wijk>();
```

To iterate over it:

```
foreach(var item in Uden)
{
     var myInt = item.Tijd;
     var myString = item.Wijken;
    //here do whatever you want with the values
}
```